# Kafka consumer multiple instances calling rest service, results duplicate records in DB

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, race-condition, spring-kafka, spring-rest

I'm using Spring boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE. My database is DB2. I'm using Spring Data Jpa in my rest service.

I have a kafka consumer, topic I'm trying to consume has 10 partitions. My kafka consumer is doing batch processing in chunks of 100.I do have 10 instances of kafka consumer.

I'm calling a rest service, which takes List as input - what it does is from that List it tries to find out any existing entries in DB & for the missing entries it tries to add/save to DB. As 10 instances of kafka consumer are running, each invokes w/ it's own list - I am seeing duplicate entries for some of the records in relevant table. My table has a sequence which is generated automatically. My unique criteria is not sequence column while trying to find existing entries. It seems like race condition

Any pointers how can I resolve this.

Comment: You need to put all instances in the same consumer `group.id` so Kafka will distribute the partitions across the instances. You need at least as many partitions as instances. If they are in different groups, each instance will get all the records.

Comment: Topic has 10 partitions, we do have 10 consumers with same group.id. Multiple records (around 200 records) in kafka, can have same set of fields/attributes my unique criteria in rest service is based on. If one consumer picks 100 records from those & start processing. One of other consumers from remaining 9, can pick other 100 records which results in duplicate entries in DB

Comment: So what is the question? This seems unrelated to Spring or Kafka at all; it seems like you just need to structure your DB SQL updates/queries/locks to avoid the duplicates. So the question should be directed to the database experts.

Comment: `If one consumer picks 100 records from those & start processing.` are u sure that the 2nd kafka consumer read from the topic before the 1st kafka consumer sent the ack-s?

Comment: Each consumer connects to differ partition, so we don't have issue w/ acknowledgements here. we came up w/ solution to batch/group messages by unique criteria across different messages & assign a key w/ hash of unique criteria

Comment: If you're owner of the producer you should use a key so that each message sent with that key will go over the same partition and consequently consumers istances will do their own job on an isolated set of data without having duplicates